# How to continuously read data from text file - Java

Tags: java, file, jtextarea, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have been trying to get data to be written from command prompt to a JTextArea, but it doesn't want to work for me, so I tried writing the data to a text file. SO far it writes one line then stops, so I need to continuously read from the text file until I stop it. Here is my code: `

```
try {
        File consoleLog = new File("tempConsole.txt");    
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c minecraft.lnk");
        //writes the text from the console to tempConsole.txt
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter consoleOutputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("tempConsole.txt"));
        consoleOutputWriter.write("" + input);
        consoleOutputWriter.newLine();
        //reads the tempConsole.txt
        BufferedReader consoleOutputReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("tempConsole.txt"));
        //writes the tempConsole.txt to the on-sceen JTextArea.
        String outputFromTemp = consoleOutputReader.readLine(); 
        console.setText(outputFromTemp);
        consoleOutputWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {`
```

Thank you for your help, I have been scouring my brain and the internet for hours with no luck :/

Comment: You should start by using the readLine() method of your BufferedReader to get the input. Right now this line consoleOutputWriter.write("" + input); uses "toString()" which most certainly is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))


String line2;
while ((line2 = in.readLine()) != null) {
//do something
}
```